# League of Legends on Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, wine, playonlinux

Has anyone got **League of Legends** working on Linux Mint 18? I'm using the "Wine" plugin "Play on Linux" and it crashes on startup everytime.

Comment: Try Lutris: https://askubuntu.com/a/1043951/114641

Answer (score 0):

I think your PC doesn't support League of Legends .

In Linux some games doesn't work, You can try to check if your PC supports  [requirements.](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/it/articles/201752654-Requisiti-di-sistema-minimi-e-consigliati)

If your PC has the requirements, you can install a virtual machine with Windows 7/8/10. 
If your PC has 4GB, put 2GB in Virtual machine, If your PC has 8GB, put 4GB in virtual machine etc.

You can install a virtual machine using [this tutorial.](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/how-to-install-windows-7-in-virtualbox-guide-hatryst)

Comment: Have you run LOL on a virtual machine? I was going to try that but someone said to try Play on Linux.

Comment: LOL doesn't work on Wine, Probably It will doesn't on Play On Linux. You can try on Play On Linux, but I suggest you to use a virtual box with 2/4GB ram, It works good.

Comment: I'm able to play League in Elementary OS. It's not quite as smooth as running in Windows, but it runs well enough to enjoy the game.

VirtualBox didn't work for me. The game crashes on startup. From what I've read, it's typically graphics card related. VB has experimental D3D support.

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, it seems to depend on the version of League of Legends.

You might look at WineHQ.

Version 6 scores highly [What Wine HQ says, based on 179 comments](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33303)

While Version7 scores very poorly [What WineHQ says, based on 65 comments](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=34726)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Wine. The latest version is 2.21-staging; also remember to set it in the Play on Linux configuration.